# C# Color lines in rich textbox from the start of a "#" symbol

Tags: c#, comments, richtextbox, code-editor

So, I am working on a "code editor", and I want to make comments look colorful.
I got a solution, however, it's poor. Problems like this happens:

I am a kinda-newbie with c#, so forgive me for my dumb mistakes
My code:

```
        private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        int index = richTextBox1.SelectionStart;
        int line = richTextBox1.GetLineFromCharIndex(index);
        this.CheckKeyword("#", Color.Green, 0);
        if(richTextBox1.Lines[line].StartsWith("#")) {
            richTextBox1.Select(index, richTextBox1.Lines[line].Length);
            richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Green;
            richTextBox1.Select(index, 0);
            return;
        }
        this.CheckKeyword("while", Color.Purple, 0);
        this.CheckKeyword("if", Color.Green, 0);
    }
```

EDIT:
http://pastebin.com/aztYGqf9
Using this code now, everything's working, except that new lines can be affected too to be green.
http://prnt.sc/dsbpvu

Comment: can you post your CheckKeyword method?

Comment: put actuall jpg link I cant see that

Comment: @Dispersia http://pastebin.com/gkvKt67x (Was seen on another stackoverflow)

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary https://i.imgur.com/DttHyi7.jpg https://i.imgur.com/mPDkVDp.jpg https://i.imgur.com/zWRnqGc.jpg

Comment: What's the stack trace? What's the actual line it blows up on? It's an out of range -- have you tried checking your indexes or debugging to see why they are out of range? C# is 0-based index, so if you get anything that's `< 0`, it's going to go boom  ;)

Comment: @TyCobb Woops, I'm an idiot. I needed to check if the length of lines is higher than 0. I tried rewriting the code a bit: http://pastebin.com/eJaSsPZv This works better, but now I can't make a new line, and everytime I type, the selection point is set before the #. I must be unseeing something :l